# Odds of first draw vs last draw

Tags: probability, random

I have debated with myself for a while as to whether, when doing a random draw for multiple prizes, should the 'major' prize be drawn first or last?  I would (as a consumer) expect that the odds or chances of winning the major prize should be smaller than than the minor prizes.  So lets say there are 1000 entries and 1 major prize and 2 minor prizes.  Am i correct to say that if the major prize was drawn first the odds for any one entry would be 1 in 1000 of winning, but if it was drawn third (and winning tickets were not returned to the draw) it would be 1 in 1000 multiplied by 1 in 999 multiplied by 1 in 998? ie much lower odds.

Answer (score 2):

If the major prize is given to one of $1000$ people uniformly randomly, then the probability of any one person receiving the prize is, as you correctly stated, $$\frac{1}{1000}$$

If the major prize is given to one person of the $998$ remaining people randomly after two other prizes are given randomly, then the probability of any one of the original $1000$ people receiving the prize is still

$$\frac{999}{1000}\cdot\frac{998}{999}\cdot\frac{1}{998} = \frac{1}{1000}$$

This calculation is the probability that a person is *not* given the first minor prize, then *not* given the second minor prize, and finally *is* given the major prize.

Intuitively, it makes sense that it should not matter in which order the prizes are given.

Answer (score 0):

No.

All this does is ensure that the person who won the first minor prize and the person who won the second minor prize cannot win the major prize.